# C# generic method selection -- best match criteria

Tags: c#, overriding

Given the following code;

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    class Example
    {
        static void F(object x) => Console.WriteLine("F(object)");
        static void F<T>(T x) => Console.WriteLine($"F<T>(T), T is {typeof(T)}");
        public static void UsageExample()
        {
            F("abc");
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Example.UsageExample();
    }
}
```

I don't understand how the compiler is selecting which function to invoke for method; **F("abc");**. What is the criteria, how I did not implicitly invoke F("abc").

When I executed the app, I expected F("abc") to return;

> "F(object)" -- "abc" is an object and a System.String

but it return;

> "F(T), T is System.String"

instead; I did not invoke `F<string>("abc")` so how did it know to use;

> static void F(T x) => Console.WriteLine($"F(T), T is {typeof(T)}");
> ??

In other words, why doesn't `F(object x)` capture F("abc") before `static void F<T>(T x)`?

Comment: Side note: "the runtime is selecting which function to invoke" - overloads are resolved at compile time (except `dynamic`), so really there is no "runtime selecting" in the code.

Comment: I understand now, F<System.String> is a better match than F<System.Object> by definition of static void F<T>(T x) by it seems like F(object x) should capture everything before F<T>(T x).

Comment: @user2237631 - The compiler chooses the most derived overload, so a generic `T` is more derived than `object`.

Comment: https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Overloading